# Rails / Strings: How to output a different parts of a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, split

I am trying to split a string, and output the different parts, whats the best practice for rails 3 ?

String: "book_page_title"
Seperator: "_"

I want to have book, page and title as seperate variables, so that 
I can perform actions on them..

Any help is appreciated. 
Also, I am having trouble finding good reference sites, with examples like PHP have, and suggestions ?

Answer (score 4):

To split:

```
book,page,title = string.split('_')
```

And to recombine:

```
string = [book,page,title].join('_')
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
split('_')
```

method it gives array.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ruby+string+doc` in google, you will get http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html as the first result, and you can see a number of string functions in this link. You can see [split](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001165) there.

```
splitted_array = "book_page_title".split("_")
=> ["book", "page", "title"]

splitted_array.each do |string|
  #..do manipulations here
end
```

Comment: rubyprince I like this.  first answer to also address outputting the various parts.

Answer (score 0):

`"book_page_title".split("_")` will return you array of strings. So you can access every element via `[]`.

```
splitted = "book_page_title".split("_") # ["book", "page", "title"]
puts splitted[0] # gives "book"
puts splitted[1] # gives "page"
puts splitted[2] # gives "title"
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for helping, I think "var.split("_")[1]" looks clean.. love how rails can output so compact code : )

Comment: @jakobk: the credit for this compact code goes to Ruby and I too love it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "book_page_title".split("_")

a.each do |i|
  instance_variable_set("@#{i}", "value")
end

@book #=> *value*
@page #=> *value*
@title #=> *value*
```